# Set value of read-only stored property during initializing in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to implement my custom MKAnnotation. I took a look at MKAnnotation protocol(MKAnnotation.h).
It's as follow:

```
//
//  MKAnnotation.h
//  MapKit
//
//  Copyright (c) 2009-2014, Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

protocol MKAnnotation : NSObjectProtocol {

    // Center latitude and longitude of the annotation view.
    // The implementation of this property must be KVO compliant.
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }

    // Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
    @optional var title: String! { get }
    @optional var subtitle: String! { get }

    // Called as a result of dragging an annotation view.
    @optional func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}
```

Please note the coordinate property (which is a read-only stored property).
And here is how I've implemented this protocol:

```
class RWDefaultPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title:String = ""
    var subtitle:String = ""
    var groupTag:String = ""
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get {
        return self.coordinate // this is obviously wrong because property's trying to return itself
    } };


    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        super.init()
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

But obviously compiler complaints on my `init` method where I'm trying to assign to my coordinate property `Cannot assign to 'coordinate' in 'self'` obviously because it's a read-only property.

Previously in Objective-C we could overcome this issue as properties were backed by ivars.

I wish there was access modifier in Swift so I could define a private property in my class and set its value on init, and returning its value on get action of coordinate, but there is no such thing!

I don't quiet know how to fix this issue in Swift, or maybe I need to make it wide open and change my coordinate to be readable/writable?

Comment: Did you try to create a really private `coordinate` property? One that can be set during initialization and is the value returned by the public `coordinate` getter?

Comment: Why not just add a `set` to it?

Comment: @Firo, this property used to be readonly back in Objective-C and if you notice, apple has defined it as readonly in MKAnnotation.h (var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get })

Comment: @CjCoax doesn't mean your class can give it a setter. Just means the protocol won't enforce a setter and it prevents anyone that doesn't know about the actual class from setting the property.

Comment: @CjCoax, I made a mistake. Apparently you cannot do what I recommended. Setting a property in the setter actually runs into an infinite loop (since it is now set, it then calls the setter again). Sorry. See edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to just add a `setter` to it and store the information in an inner coordinate value. Since you have a getter it is still conforming to the protocol:

```
var innerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { 
    get {
        return self.innerCoordinate
    } 
    set {
        self.innerCoordinate = newValue
    }
};

init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    super.init()
    self.innerCoordinate = coordinate
}
```

This is actually how I implement readonly and private properties (with protocols and the factory pattern). I setup protocols with the public interface and classes with private variables and setters. It is actually super clean way to setup your code (and gets around the lack of protected/private properties in Swift).

---

Here is a abstracted example of what I am talking about (if you care):

```
// this is your MKAnnotation in this example
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var getterProperty: String { get }
    var setterProperty: String { set get }

    func publicFunction(someStirng: String) -> ();

}

// setup a function that returns a class conforming to your needed protocol
func SomeClassMaker() -> SomeProtocol {
    // your internal class that no one can access unless by calling the maker function
    class SomeClassInternal: NSObject, SomeProtocol {

        // private and no one can get to me!
        var innerSetterProperty = "default setter";

        var getterProperty = "default getter"

        var setterProperty: String {
            get {
                return self.innerSetterProperty;
            }
            set {
                "hit"
                self.innerSetterProperty = newValue
            }
        }

        func publicFunction(someString: String) -> ()  {
            // anyone get me
            self.getterProperty = someString;
        }

        func privateFunction() -> () {
            // no one can get me except internal functions
        }

    }

    return SomeClassInternal();
}


// create the class
var classInstance = SomeClassMaker();

// totally fine!
classInstance.setterProperty = "secret string"
// prints "secret string"
classInstance.setterProperty;

// error! no public setter for "getter"
classInstance.getterProperty = "another secret"

classInstance.publicFunction("try secret again")
// prints "try secret again"
let blahed = classInstance.getterProperty

// error!
classInstance.privateFunction()
```

Comment: @JamieForrest It does if you have access to the class, but if you design your code through protocol access then accessor classes can only get it. This is a great way to have private variables and functions. It also allows for some clean unit testing. Let me refine my answer with a thorough example... give me a sec

Comment: @JamieForrest, I edited the answer with a short example of what I was trying to explain. I also made a mistake in my original answer.

Answer (score 6):

Even though the property is `{ get }` in the protocol, that is just establishing a minimum criteria.  It's perfectly acceptable to define it as read-write:

```
class MyAnnotation:NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

Or, if you really want to keep it as read-only, you can use let:

```
class MyAnnotation:NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```